# Why does Physics SE community get irritated when a small doubt / general question is asked by students?

Tags: discussion, support

Recently I had posted two questions (fortunately [one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/112099/a-question-on-vectors#112099) is there to show you), but the response which I received from the community was too irritating. And what is wrong with the homework tag (why isn't the community removing it if you don't want any so-called "homework" questions in this community*)? Total crap.. whenever users (the ones with huge rep) see questions that beginners ask they just add the tag 'homework'.. What the. I mean even they were beginners at some point or the other. Instead of answering those simple (but damn to imp for the beginners) questions they community forces students like me to remove the questions. I would seriously recommend the community to check out mathSE's response to homework tag.

Also, I am not targeting homework tag here, but the term has entered this question only because of those users who really don't want to answer the questions and demoralize the young enthusiastic brains.

I feel homework tag is being used over here (in phySE) *to spread the message that the question is being asked by a beginner* (or maybe "noob") *so please downvote it* and *flag it* and *teach him/her how to use the homework tag* and...

I really need a response. These guys (with high rep) must learn how to help others before they continue their journey on this site. Seriously.

Comment: See a down vote here too. lol. That's actually what I expected.

Comment: Maybe due to the logical fallacy that the community not liking homework questions --> remove the tag. And the patronizing tone you adopt in the post.

Comment: Actually the tone used here is far better that the one used by the users (again, high rep) who add discouraging comments.

Comment: AND what I said is actually true.

Comment: Hm, one comment is helpfully asking you to read the definition of the tag, giving an explanation of the situation. You snubbed that. The next comment was a bit  rude, but not from a high rep, and would have been deleted if flagged (which it was, just that no mod was around to delete it). The next comment is from a high rep who answers your question for you. The next one again tries to explain the policy, after you have been reverting the edits of other community members. I don't see people being discouraging here. I see you being rude, and people trying to help you.

Comment: What is true? That not liking HW questions implies that the tag should go? I don't like the tag myself, and would rather have the policy and not the tag, however this doesn't logically follow. Not all types of questions that fall under the HW tag are off topic. Thus the tag exists.

Comment: Oh come on I came here to get the answer to that question and not to know the meaning of "Homework".

Comment: and you know what? We all are just wasting our time.

Comment: Why don't the users answer it? if they have the answer

Comment: and because they aren't answering that obviously means that they don't want rep 
=> they already have enough rep to access eveything (and show their attitude).

Comment: @HarshalGajjar: Because, they don't wanna help people unless they're *paid* :)

Comment: The users here are not beholden to answer every question they see. Also, answering such disallowed questions encourages more of them, so most don't answer. They apply the tag (which hides it from people who don't want to see HW questions, even allowed ones, on the site), and go away.

Comment: Rep has nothing to do with it. People will answer posts they are interested in. It is not up to you to dictate what they should answer. And again, you're not exactly supposed to answer questions that are disallowed by policy.

Comment: I am not dictating them to do so.

Comment: I just want to tell them that instead of wasting time they could have answered the question.

Comment: *which could provide them rep and also help me.

Comment: @HarshalGajjar In my experience, homework-like questions, which may concern a complicated or really basic problem, are not massively downvoted if the question is proper phrased, shows a clear problem, and effort to explain why you cannot solve it yourself. In your case, I suppose you worked out a few things, why not adding them to the question? It saves us some work. (Although in this case it might still have been closed because there is no physics, but that is not your point). I hope you see my point :)

Comment: Hi Harshal, I have downvoted your question. I did downvote it because it was not clear, not because it was a homework question. Even if you make your question crystal clear you will get downvotes because this website is an [undergraduate level website](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5736/31782). Here people intentionally downvote beginner question so that no more beginners could join this website. There are other sites where beginner question are allowed, like Quora, Physforums, and Phys.undrflow (you can see in my profile). I won't be able to talk to you again. Cheers.

Comment: @user31782 we aren't just an undergrad level site, we cater to physics of all levels. Beginner questions are allowed. Problem solving, is not (roughly speaking).

Comment: @HarshalGajjar, the attitude expressed by your question and comments is that this community, and especially the high-rep users, *owe* you an answer,  that you're *entitled* to an answer (*"Why don't the users answer it? if they have the answer"*).  I think you should closely examine your premises.  One or more is likely to be false.

Comment: @HarshalGajjar part of the point of the stackexchange framework is that questions are here for everyone, not just for the original asker, so the site can also serve as a reference of sorts. If we answered poorly phrased or overly specialized questions and left the questions themselves untouched this place would be an absolute mess.

Answer (score 9):

The homework tag is primarily there so that uninterested people can choose to not see a certain class of questions. Unfortunately, the tag name does not accurately reflect its meaning, the meaning includes homework-like questions which are not homework.

We have a [policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) about such questions, and while there are questions which can be tagged [homework](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) and are still on topic, *most* of them are not. This is why the tag exists, but most such questions are not well received by the community.

This community is more interested in conceptual questions (where the concept is highlighted, not when the concept ma or may not be deeply hidden inside) over problem solving. There are other forums out there if you want to discuss problem solving.

Comment: Other SE forums?

Comment: @HarshalGajjar: Nope. Other internet forums :)

Comment: And that question was related to vectors.

Comment: Now don't argue with me that it is offtopic.

Comment: @HarshalGajjar Ok, misuse of words ("off topic" is an SE-ism that is used to mean disallowed types of posts, stemming from the close reason of the same name) -- it is disallowed on this site by policy.

Comment: @HarshalGajjar it is off-topic, it does not relate to a physics concept, just mathematical details that happen to appear in physics. But your question does not have any physical interpretation or insight.